# How do I add a temporal function to click

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I'm trying to add a pause between clicks when clicking on buttons in a page.

It's giving me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined"

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('xxxxxx'); 

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        inputs[i].click();
    }, (1000 * i)) 
}
```

Not sure how else to approach it. If I remove the timeout, the clicks work properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem called "closing over the loop variable". What's happening is that when your timeout actually fires, `i` is equal to `inputs.length`, which is beyond the end of the set of inputs.

Simplest solution: use `Array#forEach` so that you have a separate closure containing each input itself and a separate, non-fluctuating copy of `i`, instead of an `i` variable that keeps changing:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('xxxxxx'); 

Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).forEach(function (input, i) {
     setTimeout(function () { 
         input.click(); 
     }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, this solved it, and gave me a new learning direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing for the input if null :

```
if (inputs[i] != null) {
inputs[i].click();}
```

and try starting the timer on document complete.